# Error on 'Extract raster values (CSV)' - Error executing algorithm 1 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'mapToPixel' See log for more details

Tags: qgis, raster, csv

I would like to extract raster values at some locations (point shapefile) in 'csv' format. I use 'Point Sampling Tool' and it works well for a raster file. However, I have hundred of raster files (rainfalls) which need batch process to work on extracting the raster values.

I have tried 'Extract raster values (CSV)' in the processing tool but the error message pops up (Error executing algorithm 1 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'mapToPixel' See log for more details). Both vector and raster files have the same projection (WGS84). I already add 'mapToPixel' attribute in the point shapefile but the error still exists.

[image: Error message from 'Extract raster values (CSV)']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the script.

To workaround, edit [qgis install dir]/python/plugins/processing/script/scripts/Extract_raster_values_to_CSV.py (not sure of exact path, I run QGIS on Linux) and replace line 88:

```
        (rX, rY) = raster.mapToPixel(x, y, geoTransform)
```

With:

```
        (rX, rY) = mapToPixel(x, y, geoTransform)
```

The problem:

The `mapToPixel` function is defined in the processing.tools.raster module which is imported into the local namespace by the `Extract_raster_values_to_CSV.py` i.e `from processing.tools.raster import *`

The script then tries to use the function, but it prefixes the raster module namespace, but the raster module wasn't imported, only the functions defined in the module were. Additionally, a raster variable was set to a gdal.Dataset object on line 14 of the script.

Edit: issue reported at the [QGIS Bug Tracker](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11205).

Comment: I try to run batch process to extract raster to CSV once I corrected the bug. But it always stops at the 13th iteration (no matter I change the different raster input). Many thanks.

Comment: @deriham you should [ask a new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)