# Error on 'Extract raster values to CSV' in batch process in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, csv, batch

The Extract values (csv) contained a bug in the script. The below link shows how to correct the bug. [Error on 'Extract raster values (CSV)' - Error executing algorithm 1 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'mapToPixel' See log for more details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113771/error-on-extract-raster-values-csv-error-executing-algorithm-1-dataset-o)

However, a batch process always stops at the 8th iteration when I use the corrected extract raster values to CSV script (no matter I change the different raster inputs).

Here are the error messages at 8th iteration.

```
**Algorithm Extract raster values (CSV) starting...**

Prepare algorithm 0: Points from vector
Parameters: Input_raster =D:\IDD_RCP\8.5\Averaged_RCP8.5_Nan_basin\2080-2099\ta\RCP_8_5_mrc3_2080_2099_ta_mon10_RCP_8.tif, Input_vector =D:\Average_Raster_over_Vector\Nan_basin_centroid_WGS.shp
Outputs: Output_layer =C:\Users\NORASET\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\592fdd79ac8f43d4bffc01e05dc89310\Outputlayer.shp
OK. Execution took 1.145 ms (1 outputs).
Prepare algorithm 1: Extract raster values to CSV
Parameters: Input_raster =D:\IDD_RCP\8.5\Averaged_RCP8.5_Nan_basin\2080-2099\ta\RCP_8_5_mrc3_2080_2099_ta_mon10_RCP_8.tif, Input_vector =C:\Users\NORASET\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\592fdd79ac8f43d4bffc01e05dc89310\Outputlayer.shp, Transform_vector_to_raster_CRS =False
Failed

**Error executing algorithm 1 [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor See log for more details**
```

[image: Error on Batch Processing when using Extract raster values (CSV)]

Comment: @Luke Prepare algorithm 1: Extract raster values to CSV
Parameters: Input_raster =D:\IDD_RCP\4.5\Averaged_RCP4.5_Nan_basin\2040-2059\RCP_4_5_mir5_2040_2059_ta_mon 5_RCP_4.tif, Input_vector =C:\Users\NORASET\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\c2b9f6337c1541cd82d9ff299e29d375\Outputlayer.shp, Transform_vector_to_raster_CRS =False
Failed
Error executing algorithm 1 [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor See log for more d

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information. Putting it in comments means potential answerers may miss it.